# Filter Android StrictMode violations by duration

Tags: android, android-strictmode

Is there a way to filter StrictMode violations based on duration?

It's getting a bit annoying having these

```
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=6 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskWriteViolation: policy=31 violation=1
```

poisoning my logcat.

I think StrictMode is a useful feature, but I'd like to deal only with violations with a duration greater than, let's say, 50 ms, in the first development phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The StrictMode API does not support filtering by duration.

But you can easily do so by filtering StrictMode's log reports:

**A. Configure StrictMode to write errors to log:**

```
public void onCreate() {
     if (DEVELOPER_MODE) {
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                 .detectDiskReads()
                 .detectDiskWrites()
                 .detectNetwork()
                 .penaltyLog() //<---------- write reports to log
                 .build());
     }
     super.onCreate();
}
```

**B. Read logcat lines:**

```
logcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d"});
br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logcat.getInputStream()),4*1024);
String line;
  final StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
  String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          filterLogLine(line)
    }
}
```

**C. filter lines by duration:**

```
void filterLogLine(String line) {
    use StringTokenizer to parse the line
    get value of "~duration"
    and filter if lesser than your threshold
}
```

I leave you to figure out the exact details of the line parsing.