# Android StrictModeDiskReadViolation when app startup

Tags: android

I've enabled `StrictMode` on my app by code:

```
public void onCreate() {
    setStrictMode();
    super.onCreate();
}

private void setStrictMode() {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll()
            .penaltyLog()
            .penaltyDeath()
            .build());
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll()
            .penaltyLog()
            .build());
}
```

I found a crash when startup with log below :

StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=0 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=95 violation=2
                                                                             at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1137)
                                                                             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:182)
                                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
                                                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                                             at android.graphics.Typeface.getFullFlipFont(Typeface.java:582)
                                                                             at android.graphics.Typeface.getFontPathFlipFont(Typeface.java:530)
                                                                             at android.graphics.Typeface.SetFlipFonts(Typeface.java:717)
                                                                             at android.graphics.Typeface.SetAppTypeFace(Typeface.java:844)
                                                                             at android.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:108)

I think is an io operate on main thread violation, My device is samsung s6, android version 5.1.1, but I can't find the method `getFullFlipFont` anywhere, if I disable strictmode it will be alright, where is the io violation happen?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to happens on Samsung's phone. I have the same problem when running `StrictMode` on Samsung S7. But the issue is not there when running on Nexus 6P.

Two ways to resolve this. One is to turn on your Strict Mode after your application `super.onCreate().` This is not ideal, as I believe you'll encounter other issue along the way that doesn't belong to your code.

The other one is to suppress it. You could check out [this page.](https://medium.com/@elye.project/android-strict-mode-selective-code-suppression-37ee0d999f6b#.wismc9ryh) That's using Kotlin, but you could think of a way to work for Java, but a little more hassle.

Optionally, you could consider trying to suppress using this approach [Filter Android StrictMode violations by duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056157/filter-android-strictmode-violations-by-duration)