# StrictMode policy violation: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=327711 violation=2 at Application super.onCreate

Tags: android

When I turn on the strict mode detect All, my App crashes super.onCreate() of application (i.e. before even I have any of my code doing anything).

My application onCreate turning on the strict mode as below

```
override fun onCreate() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                        .detectAll()
                        .penaltyLog()
                        .penaltyDeath().build())
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(
                StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                        .detectAll()
                        .penaltyLog()
                        .penaltyDeath().build())
    }
    super.onCreate()

    // Some other code
}
```

The error I got (which is on the line of `super.onCreate()`)

```
D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=98 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=327711 violation=2
                                                             at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1263)
                                                             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:182)
                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                             at android.graphics.Typeface.getFullFlipFont(Typeface.java:584)
                                                             at android.graphics.Typeface.getFontPathFlipFont(Typeface.java:532)
                                                             at android.graphics.Typeface.SetFlipFonts(Typeface.java:719)
                                                             at android.graphics.Typeface.SetAppTypeFace(Typeface.java:846)
                                                             at android.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:110)
                                                             at com.mypackage.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.kt:40)
```

Is this an expected error we should ignore, or is this something that we should fix?

Comment: Line 40 of `onCreate` is reading from the disk(`onReadFromDisk`).

Comment: That's the `super.onCreate` of the application. What can I do about that?

Comment: Nothing. Just focus on the `StrictMode` violations from the code that you have written.

Comment: Oh thanks. Is there a way to suppress these error/warning, so that the strictmode would only check the code of my package/module?

Comment: Not that I know of. See this to try and filter them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056157/filter-android-strictmode-violations-by-duration.

Comment: Thanks @Jared. I have got a way to suppress it in coding. https://medium.com/@elye.project/android-strict-mode-selective-code-suppression-37ee0d999f6b#.rfcyw3n5j

Comment: Nice. Post an answer showing how to do it.

Comment: Sure, posted my answer. If you like it, you could give a vote to it :) Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the error are device specific. It happens on Samsung S7, but not Nexus 6P. Hence it's not something I would be fixing. Hence the best way to suppress it.

The below is the example how I got it suppressed. You could wrap those functions into an Util Class.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate() {
    turnOnStrictMode()
    permitDiskReads{
        super.onCreate()
    }

    // Some other code
}


fun turnOnStrictMode() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                        .detectAll()
                        .penaltyLog()
                        .penaltyDeath().build())
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(
                StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                        .detectAll()
                        .penaltyLog()
                        .penaltyDeath().build())
    }
}

fun permitDiskReads(func: () -> Any) : Any {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        val oldThreadPolicy = StrictMode.getThreadPolicy()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder(oldThreadPolicy)
                .permitDiskReads().build())
        val anyValue = func()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(oldThreadPolicy)

        return anyValue
    } else {
        return func()
    }
}
```

Refers [to this](https://medium.com/@elye.project/android-strict-mode-selective-code-suppression-37ee0d999f6b#.simbpoeen) for more detail.

Comment: Just make sure you do not do any diskreads: `permitDiskReads`.

Comment: The permitDiskReads only applies to the code that is sent to the function, after that the checks turn on again for all through the `StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(oldThreadPolicy)`

Answer (score 1):

Move the statement 'super.onCreate()' before the StrictMode methods in fun onCreate(). Check this article for details. [Walk through hell with Android StrictMode](https://medium.com/@elye.project/walk-through-hell-with-android-strictmode-7e8605168032)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Java version

```
public class StrictModeManager {

private static boolean enabled = false;

private StrictModeManager() {}

public static void enableStrictMode() {
    enabled = true;
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder threadPolicyBuilder = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectDiskReads()
            .detectDiskWrites()
            .detectNetwork()
            .penaltyLog()
            .penaltyDropBox();

    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder vmPolicyBuilder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
            .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
            .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
            .detectLeakedRegistrationObjects()
            .penaltyLog()
            .penaltyDropBox()
            .penaltyDeath();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(threadPolicyBuilder.build());
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(vmPolicyBuilder.build());

}

public static void allowDiskReads(Runnable runnable) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy oldThreadPolicy = null;
    if (enabled) {
        oldThreadPolicy = StrictMode.getThreadPolicy();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder(oldThreadPolicy).permitDiskReads().build());
    }
    runnable.run();
    if (oldThreadPolicy != null) StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(oldThreadPolicy);
   }
}
```

And to use it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) StrictModeManager.enableStrictMode();
    StrictModeManager.allowDiskReads(App.super::onCreate);

    // Code here
}
```

Comment: Not working out-of-the-box. On java, the 'App.super::onCreate' is not being recognized and I cannot think of good way to cast Runnable to/from the super in this case.

Comment: should be `super::onCreate` not `App.super::onCreate`