# App terminated after X times launching a new Activity

Tags: android, logcat, termination

I have a simple app with 2 activities: MainActivity (with 2 Fragments) and GameActivity.
In one of the Fragments "FragmentHome" I have a FloatingButton which upon press launches my GameActivity.
When the game ends I show an AlertDialog with a button which upon click does:  `GameActivity.this.onBackPressed();` which returns the user back to FragmentHome where he can launch the game again.

The problematic scenario is: the user launches the game (from the FragmentHome FloatingButton), plays it, the game is over in few seconds and user is directed back to FragmentHome where he launches the game again;   if to repeat this 7-8 times then at some point the FloatingButton click will just terminate the application without a logcat error thrown.   The only weird 'hint' in logcat I can see is *D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation* which does not really say much about the app termination.

I monitored the App memory usage   (from the Android device itself):   it is normal, between 53MB and 66MB.

My FloatingButton on click:

```
myView.findViewById(R.id.btnStartGame).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!AppController.appOnline) {
                    Snackbar.make(lstLuckyUsers, getString(R.string.txt_no_internet), 2000).show();
                    return;
                }

                Intent gameIntent = new Intent(FragmentHome.this.context, GameActivity.class);
                FragmentHome.this.context.startActivity(gameIntent);
            }
        });
```

My GameActivity AlertDialog button click:

```
MaterialButton btnOK = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        if (btnOK != null)
            btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // close dialog and game Activity
                    gameOverDialog.dismiss();
                    GameActivity.this.onBackPressed();
                }
            });
```

Could you please advise where shall I look for the problem? It feels like the Garbage Collector is not doing its job as expected or there is a Framework I use and this brings the troubles.
The dependencies are plain standard:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mygame.mygame"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.3'

    // volley lib
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    // FAN Ad
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.0.0'

    // Google In-App Review
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1'
}
```

Comment: are you reading something from the disk ? Coz that may cause the error if you read a particular file/code fragment multiple times in a short span

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427478/strictmode-policy-violation-android-os-strictmodestrictmodediskreadviolation Check this for a better explanation

Comment: @Aditya, I am not reading anything from the disk.   Thanks for the link provided, but the discussion there is dealing with suppressing this warning message at all and the app in that topic really crashes upon start