# How to fix StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=17 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation on call to startActivity(intent)

Tags: android, android-strictmode

We have enabled strict mode in one of our activities to check for violations, getting a trace pointing to the **startActivity()** call belonging to the Activity class. I'm not sure why it's throwing this issue, as i do not see any IO calls being triggered. Mentioning the trace below.

````
     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1659)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.applyBlockGuardPolicy(SQLiteConnection.java:1630)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:1298)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:838)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:157)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:144)
     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:238)
     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:287)
     at com.android.server.enterprise.storage.EdmStorageProviderBase.getBooleanList(EdmStorageProviderBase.java:133)
     at com.android.server.enterprise.storage.EdmStorageProviderBase.getBoolean(EdmStorageProviderBase.java:1041)
     at com.android.server.enterprise.storage.EdmStorageProvider.getBoolean(EdmStorageProvider.java:249)
     at com.samsung.android.knox.custom.KnoxCustomManagerService.getProKioskState(KnoxCustomManagerService.java:2070)
     at com.samsung.android.knox.custom.ProKioskManager.getProKioskState(ProKioskManager.java:463)
     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.chooseBestActivity(PackageManagerService.java:11862)
     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.resolveIntentInternal(PackageManagerService.java:11734)
     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.access$12900(PackageManagerService.java:663)
     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$PackageManagerInternalImpl.resolveIntent(PackageManagerService.java:33709)
     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.resolveIntent(ActivityTaskSupervisor.java:819)
     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter$Request.resolveActivity(ActivityStarter.java:620)
     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:760)
     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1873)
     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1744)
     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivity(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1697)
     at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityTaskManager.java:1132)
     at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.onTransact(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:6223)
     at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1215)
     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1179)
 # via Binder call with stack:
     at android.os.StrictMode.readAndHandleBinderCallViolations(StrictMode.java:2497)
     at android.os.Parcel.readExceptionCode(Parcel.java:2382)
     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2343)
     at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:2897)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1743)
     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5473)
     at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:728)
     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5431)
     at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:709)
     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5817)
     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5770)```

The [following post][1] details the issue wrt the onCreate() call back , i did find more posts similar to the same, need help wrt the startActivity() call 

Device details of the test device
Samsung M31, Android 12 


[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51829388/6738937
````